# Chunking results onto existing Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, chunking

I am facing an issue which I am looking to overcome.  I have a Report that can have many different types of data sets.  I have all relations set up appropriately.

Within my show function, when I need to pass this Object to the frontend I do

```
$dataArray = Report::with(['data_set_a', 'data_set_b', 'data_set_c'])
               ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('id', $id)->first();
```

Now in most cases this works perfectly, data is passed to the frontend.  However, for some reports, `data_set_a` has about 20k rows.  Locally this is not a problem, but on my live system nothing loads.

I have checked the logs, and mod_security is stating `inbound anomaly score exceeded`.  I imagine it is not liking the fact that the data set is large and it is blocking it.

As such, I was thinking about adding this data set manually using chunking.  So I am attempting something like this

```
$dataArray = Report::with(['data_set_b', 'data_set_c'])
               ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('id', $id)->first();

DataSetA::where('report_id', $report->id)
                ->chunk(500, function($data)  {
                    foreach ($data as $row) {
                            $dataArray['data_set_a'] = array(
                                'cust_id' => $row->cust_id,
                                'colOne' => $row->colOne,
                                'colTwo' => $row->colTwo,
                                'colThree' => $row->colThree
                            );
                        );
                    }
                });
```

However, I seem to be having issues with the syntax.  How can I chunk this data from `data_set_a` onto the dataArray?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the error is due to size of data-set? Does the issue only occur with large data-sets?

Comment: Yes, works perfect with smaller data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `dataArray` into your chunk function, and append each row to array, instead of overwriting it:

```
$dataArray['data_set_a'] = [];
DataSetA::where('report_id', $report->id)
                ->chunk(500, function($data) use ($dataArray)  {
                    foreach ($data as $row) {
                            $dataArray['data_set_a'][] = array(
                                'cust_id' => $row->cust_id,
                                'colOne' => $row->colOne,
                                'colTwo' => $row->colTwo,
                                'colThree' => $row->colThree
                            );
                        );
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks.  Getting a strange error, Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Report has no effect

Comment: Convert the `dataArray` into an array, instead of collection: `->first()->toArray()`